# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x11241ab30) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x1109ef598)

Tags: swift

```
group.issues = temp.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor]) as! NSMutableArray
```

The system version is iOS 11.0, Xcode 9.0.

How can we solve this?

Comment: The message is clear: You cannot cast a Swift `Array` to `NSMutableArray`.  Don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all. With the `var` keyword you get mutability for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you're actually doing, you're probably better off using a mutable Swift array, declared as a `var`. However, if you really do need reference semantics for some reason, you can make an `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
group.issues = NSMutableArray(array: temp.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor]))
```

The reason you cannot just cast it is because the Objective-C bridge bridges a Swift array to an immutable `NSArray`, which would throw an exception if you tried to call the mutating methods on it.

Again, though, the best thing to do is just use a Swift array, by declaring the `issues` property as a `var`:

```
struct Group {
    ...

    var issues: [String] // or whatever type goes inside the array

    ...
}
```

Then just assign it like:

```
group.issues = temp.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor])
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Easy and simple way

```
let arrPicOne = temparrpicFind as! [Any]
let arrPicTwo = temparrpic as! [Any]
let picResult = arrPicOne + arrPicTwo

arrGpic = NSMutableArray(array:picResult)
```