# Not able to cast __SwiftDeferredNSArray to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have an array defined like so..

```
var filteredData = [[String: Any]]()
```

But when I try to convert it like so,

```
      var filteredArray = filteredData as! NSMutableArray //CRASH HERE
      dic =  filteredArray[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
      cell.Sched_celltitle.text = "\(dic["name"]!)"
```

I get a crash like mentioned above saying `Could not cast value of type 'Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x103..) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x200..).`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357236/could-not-cast-value-of-type-swift-swiftdeferrednsarray-0x11241ab30-to-nsm

Comment: Checked that same post @Sh_Khan..and also many other posts..but it's still crashing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the immutable types `NSMutable...` collection types are not related to native Swift collection types.

You cannot even cast the type from `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` in Objective-C.

Just don't do that. `NSMutable...` collection types are pointless in Swift. The native types declared as `var`iable are mutable for free.

```
var filteredData = [[String: Any]]()

...

let item = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
cell.Sched_celltitle.text = item["name"] as? String
```

A much better way is to create a custom struct replacing the quite unspecified `[String:Any]` dictionary